# Add new object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, fs

I'm struggling to push a new object into an array. At the moment the code below seems to be simply overwriting a single object. I can see the data I want to push to the array going through the console but it's just not storing a new object. Any ideas?

```
fs.readFile('check.json', function (err, check) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var newData = JSON.parse(check);

    var tempData =[];
    for (var index=0; index<newData.length; index++){
        tempData.push(newData);
        }
    tempData = newData;
});
```

Comment: You are assigning the last element to the array at the end? 
    tempData = newData;

Comment: you're overwriting the `tempData` array by assigning it with `newData` in the last line

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach for iterating arrays and then pushing objects to them would be this

```
var tempData =[];
for (var index=0; index<newData.length; index++){
    tempData.push(newData[index]);
    //                     ^add index
}
//tempData = newData; remove assignment which overwrites array
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you offer any insight into how that pushes externally with fs? The external json comes back as undefined. Travis J